# strings are cast differently depending on value

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

It would seem like when a number as a string is less than zero it is cast as an integer, but if it is greater than zero it is cast as a decimal.  Why does this happen?

```python
spark.sql("select case when '1.24' > 1.23 then 1 else 0 end as test").show()

+----+
|test|
+----+
|   1|
+----+

spark.sql("select case when '0.24' > 0 then 1 else 0 end as test").show()

+----+
|test|
+----+
|   0|
+----+
```

Comment: what happens if you try `select case when '0.24' > 0.0 then 1 else 0 end as test`?

Comment: Oh, that works.  This makes sense and is weird at the same time.  Thanks

Comment: Could you  please try `select case when '05' > 0.01 then 1 else 0 end as test` ? I think everything will be casted to strings, not to integers or float

Comment: Weirdly, `SELECT '1.23' > 1.24, '0.24' > 0` returns `false, true` in HIVE. @QPSK Can you try `spark.sql("SELECT '1.23' > 1.24, '0.24' > 0").show()` (without the `CASE WHEN`)? That also seems to work for me.

Comment: in spark, it returns false, false.  In hive it returns false, true.  This is a spark thing I guess.  The solution of just use 0.0 for literals is good enough for me.